# Privacy flag in Data Processor results

Tags: extension, data-processor

I'm using the Data Processor extension to generate a report and dashlet showing recent new signups through Drupal, for our staff to follow up with an e-mail or phone call.

I'd like to get an indicator against the search results for those users who have ticked 'Do not e-mail' or 'Do not call' so staff don't have to click into each card individually to find out whether or not to contact them. Obviously I could make another column using the relevant fields, but is there a way to get Data Processor to display the little graphical privacy flag that appears in standard CiviCRM search results?

Comment: Do you mean to show donot email or call in single column?

Comment: Together with the number/e-mail address, yes. With the little 'Stop' icon, as is CiviCRM's standard search behaviour.